# Why is Kantorovich optimal transport dual not smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two separable metric spaces such that any probability measure on $X$ (or $Y$ ) is a Radon measure (i.e. they are Radon spaces). Let $c: X \times Y \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ be a Borel-measurable function. The Kantorovich problem is

$$\inf \left\{\int_{X \times Y} c(x, y) \mathrm{d} \gamma(x, y) \mid \gamma \in \Gamma(\mu, \nu)\right\}$$

where $\Gamma(\mu, v)$ denotes the collection of all probability measures on $X \times Y$ with marginals $\mu$ on $X$ and $v$ on
Y. It can be shown that a minimizer for this problem always exists when the cost function $c$ is lower semi-continuous and $\Gamma(\mu, v)$ is a tight collection of measures (which is guaranteed for Radon spaces $X$.
and $Y$ ).

Under mild conditions, the minimum of the Kantorovich problem is equal to
$$
\sup \left(\int_{X} \varphi(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)+\int_{Y} \psi(y) \mathrm{d} \nu(y)\right)
$$
where the supremum runs over all pairs of bounded and continuous functions $\varphi: X \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $\psi: Y \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that
$$
\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \leq c(x, y)
$$

I read everywhere that this dual problem is not smooth in $(\varphi, \psi)$. What does it mean and why is it the case ? By not smooth, do we mean that the Fréchet derivatives do not exist ?

Comment: Saying the dual problem is not smooth in $(\varphi,\psi)$ does not make any sense. Can you give a reference?

Comment: For example "Stochastic Optimization for Large-scale Optimal Transport" by Genevay et al. More precisely, page 4, just before point 3, they talk about a function $h_0$. That's the important part.

Comment: I don't see in this paper anything about the dual problem not being smooth in $\varphi,\psi$

Comment: It says that $h_{0}(x, \psi) \stackrel{\text { def. }}{=} \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \psi(y) \mathrm{d} \nu(y)+\min _{y \in \mathcal{Y}} c(x, y)-\psi(y)$ is not smooth in $\psi$, which is the same

Comment: Where exactly it says that?

Comment: Page 4, in the "stochastic optimization formulations" paragraph, toward the end of the paragraph.

Comment: The word "smooth" does not appear in that paragraph. Maybe I'm looking at a different version? I found this link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08527.pdf

Comment: Indeed we're looking at different versions. Here is the published version: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6566-stochastic-optimization-for-large-scale-optimal-transport.pdf